# Hiding Layer Source using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, data-source

I am developing a plugin for QGIS that loads the layers of a WFS.

For security reasons I would like the user could not know the layer source.
How can I remove the path of the layer in `Vector Properties Dialog-> Layer Info -> Layer Source`? and in the tooltip of the layer in the Legend?

I have been searching but I can not find a way to modify the Vector Layer Dialog to disable functions or make other modifications.

Comment: Your user does not need to be very clever for finding out where the GetFeatures are sent.  How about setting up something like your own GeoServer that works as a WFS proxy? Then your user could only see the address of your WFS but not the one where the data really come.

Comment: just for clarification, where is this dialog?`Layer properties > information` and Path value?

Comment: The route is shown in the properties of the layer, in the Information section

Comment: If the user really wants to find out the data source he will find it out. You can always use something like fiddler and set the proxy in qgis so all requests and responses are shown in fiddler.

Comment: Thank you all, I think that in the end I will look at the option of using a proxy